# Is there a way to configure willPopScope to catch a custom pop navigation in flutter?

Tags: flutter, navigation, alert

Is there a way to configure willPopScope to catch a custom pop navigation as follows? I have a custom Raisedbutton widget with onPressed to navigate back to the previous page.

But willPopScope doesn't catch the navigation as it does for the AppBar back button. I'm not sure if this is even possible. Please advise. Thanks!

```
WillPopScope(
 child: Scaffold(
  body: Container(
   child: Center(
    child: RaisedButton(
     onPressed:(){
      return Navigator.pop(context);
     },
     child: Text("Go Back),
    ),
   ),
  ),
 ),
 onWillPop: () async {
  // code to show a modal
 }
);
```

Comment: are you trying to show a modal if the user pops the screen? like a "are you sure" kinda of modal? or you want to show something over your previous screen?

Comment: @MarianoZorrilla Yes, I'm trying to show a "are you sure" modal. It works when the back button on the app bar or the actual back button on phone is clicked, but not for this custom back button on the screen.

Comment: I dropped a solution, let me know if that one works.

Answer (score 11):

Here is a full example to achieve your goal. **WillPopScope** needs a `maybePop` call in order to do your logic:

```
class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  MyHomePage({Key key, this.title}) : super(key: key);

  final String title;

  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text(widget.title),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: RaisedButton(
          child: Text('Jump To Next Screen'),
          onPressed: () => Navigator.of(context)
              .push(MaterialPageRoute(builder: (_) => ModalScreen())),
        ),
      ), // This trailing comma makes auto-formatting nicer for build methods.
    );
  }
}

class ModalScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _ModalScreenState createState() => _ModalScreenState();
}

class _ModalScreenState extends State<ModalScreen> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return WillPopScope(
      child: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          leading: InkResponse(
            child: Icon(Icons.arrow_back),
            onTap: () => Navigator.of(context).maybePop(),
          ),
        ),
        backgroundColor: Colors.blue,
        body: Center(
          child: RaisedButton(
            child: Text('Let\'s go back'),
            onPressed: () {
              Navigator.of(context).maybePop();
            },
          ),
        ),
      ),
      onWillPop: () => _willPop(context),
    );
  }

  Future<bool> _willPop(BuildContext context) {
    final completer = Completer<bool>();
    showModalBottomSheet(
        context: context,
        builder: (buildContext) {
          return SizedBox(
            height: 200,
            child: Column(
              children: [
                Padding(
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 20),
                  child: Text('Are you sure?'),
                ),
                MaterialButton(
                    child: Text('YES'),
                    onPressed: () {
                      completer.complete(true);
                      Navigator.of(context).pop();
                    }),
                MaterialButton(
                    child: Text('NO'),
                    onPressed: () {
                      completer.complete(true);
                    }),
              ],
            ),
          );
        });

    return completer.future;
  }
}
```

Once you return `true` for your modal, you also need to **Pop** the screen as the modal has his own context needed to be popped.

Final result is the following:

[image]

Comment: great solution!  one minor correction is necessary though, when user clicks NO then `completer.complete(false);`  instead of `true`

Comment: He wanted to dismiss the popup as well and that's the way of doing it. For the confirmation one I have an extra pop to also dismiss the screen.

Comment: when user clicks YES then: 
 `Navigator.of(context, rootNavigator: true).pop();  completer.complete(true);`.  when NO then;  `Navigator.of(context, rootNavigator: true).pop(); 
 completer.complete(false);`